# Android storing Media - web server

Tags: android, node.js, express, media

Issue: I want to upload a video or image with size >= 1MB to a web server and store it in a file but it takes about 2 mins to upload it. Any ideas about how to upload it in a shorter time?

I am using node.js as my server and the `express-fileupload` module to store the files.

Comment: You can use the volley library to send the image from android to server in more secure and efficient.
I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Show your code that uploads the video file.

Answer (score 0):

According to my Knowledge there is no such module which can speed up the uploading in your case. As it all depends on several things like Your network speed, your server's traffic handling capability, etc.

- But You can use Volley library that will handle to put your image and videos packets on the network channel as fast as possible other than that you can't do anything else.

Good Practice :
- Try to decrease your image size to some KBs.
Inspiration :
Instagram store 3 copies of images of 10 KB ,100KB and the real one. Try Image compression, that will help in speeding up uploading.

Just Coz I want to write more :

INSTAGRAM Downloading from server includes 3 Steps:

All 3 images starts downloading at the same time:

1). 10 KB the blurry image but not clear at all. Show it for few seconds to user. (Stretch to fit concept)

2). 100KB less blurry but more clear. Same show it for few seconds.

3). Real big size in MBs image now downloaded, show this beautiful image to user.

Comment: is there any library can compress the videos ? i found some library in image compression but for videos i did not find anything useful for android